# How to search for text with InStr and Excel Search?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the text "General Account Section" using `InStr` and Excel's Search.

When I to use Excel's search and input the word "General" it finds the value.

When I try to search for "General Account Section" or "General " (General with a space after) it can't find the value.

The same goes with my `InStr()` function:

```vb
' Loop through entire column A
For i = 1 To eProColCount 'Rows.Count
    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A").value, "General") <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A").value
    End If
Next i ' End loop
```

When I copy the value inside the cell and paste it on the search or as a parameter on my `InStr()` it finds what I'm looking for.

I tried changing options inside the Excel's Search.

[image: Excel]

Comment: What does `=CODE(MID(A3,8,1))` return?

Comment: Your sheet with data it it may not be the Activesheet at the time of searching so wouldn't pull back the correct data. Try and use direct worksheet referencing and see if that works. I would also use a Range.Find method for this not a loop

Comment: Oh and Range.Cells takes numbers so you would need something like ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

Comment: @Tragamor - the column letter is a valid 2nd argument in `Cells` - either `1` or `"A"` would be fine.

Comment: @BigBen It returns `160`

Comment: That's a non-breaking space. Maybe replace it with a regular space.

Comment: @BigBen This solved my problem. I'm copying from another excel file I thought pasting it normally would eliminate the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

another way to read the column until it is not empty

```
Option Explicit ' it is a best practice

Sub search()
        
    Dim n As Integer ' to read the next row
    Dim myContent As String ' content of the current Cell
  
    n = 1
    
    Do While Not (IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("NameOfMySheet").Cells(n, 1)))
      
        myContent = ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("NameOfMySheet").Cells(n, 1).Value
        
        If InStr(1, myContent, "General") <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print myContent
        End If
    
    ' next row
    n = n + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```